# How to use OpenCV to achieve Extended Kalman Filter？(Filter for rotation Quaternion)

Tags: c

Is EKF just replacing the state transition matrix with the Jacobian matrix of rotation equations at this moment on the basis of Kalman?
I do not know how to modify the opencv Kalman filter into EKF for quaternions, where should I start?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  I'm not clear quite what you're asking in the body of the question.  The 'and with' confuses me; it makes more sense if you drop the 'and', but I'm not sure whether that's what you mean.  It isn't clear that you are asking about a programming question — nor where OpenCV fits into the problem.  You seem to be asking an abstract question that does not depend on OpenCV.